# system() does not work

Tags: c

My program reads and stores standard input into a char array `cmd` and then call `system(cmd)`. I printed out `cmd` and its content is what I expected. But `system(cmd)` does not save the content in `report.log`. I tried with a literal string stored in `cmd2`, and this time it worked. So what is wrong with `system(cmd)`?

And I am using Windows 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXLEN 100


char *now(){
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    return asctime(localtime(&t));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char comment[80];
    char cmd[120];

    fgets(comment, 80, stdin);
    sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> report.log", comment, now());

    printf("%s", cmd); // content of cmd is what I expect

    system(cmd); // does not work, why?

    char cmd2 = "echo 'Hello world' >> report.log";
    system(cmd2); // work


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't tou remove the trailing `\n` captured and stoted by `fgets()`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I think the `\n` at the end of the string returned by `asctime()` might be the real problem. I'm not familiar enough with how `system()` works on Windows to be sure, though.

Comment: Thanks guys, after removing trailing \n in both arrays, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem maybe with the excess `\n`s present in your inputs to `sprintf()`.

- `fgets()` scans and stores the `\n` from the `stdin`. You need to get rid of that `\n` and replace that with a null.
- `asctime()` returns a `ctime()` return style string, again ended with a newline `\n`. You need to remove (replace) that too.

You can check the following code for your reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXLEN 100


char *now(){
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    return asctime(localtime(&t));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char comment[80] = {0};
    char cmd[120] = {0};
    char * timestring = NULL;   //initialize local variables, good practice

    fgets(comment, 80, stdin);
    comment[ strlen(comment) -1] = 0;       //reomve the trailing \n taken by fgtes(), replace by null

    timestring = now();
    timestring[strlen(timestring)-1] = 0;   //remove the \n from ctime() return style string, replace b null

    sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> report.log", comment, timestring);

    printf(">> The string is : %s\n", cmd); 

    system(cmd); // should work now.. :-)

    return 0;
}
```